# how to remove border in ion-header

Tags: html, sass, ionic5, angular11

In my ionic 5 application I have HTML as following:

```html
<ion-header [translucent]="true" class="ion-no-border">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Title</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>

  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-segment value="1" [color]="segementColor" (ionChange)="onSegmentChange($event)">
      <ion-segment-button value="1" layout="icon-start">
        <ion-label>Segment 1</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    
      <ion-segment-button value="2" layout="icon-start">
        <ion-label>Segment 2</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    
      <ion-segment-button value="3" layout="icon-start">
        <ion-label>Segment 3</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

With screenshot:

[image: Screenshot Here]

My question is how can I remove the line or border occurring after the Title toolbar? I have tried with `border: none` but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

try this code::
this will put your ion-segment inside header so your title border will not show anymore.........................

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title mode="ios">Title</ion-title>

    <ion-segment value="1">
      <ion-segment-button value="1" layout="icon-start">
        <ion-label>Segment 1</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>

      <ion-segment-button value="2" layout="icon-start">
        <ion-label>Segment 2</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>

      <ion-segment-button value="3" layout="icon-start">
        <ion-label>Segment 3</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Here is OUTPUT ScreeenShot Please check::

[image: OutPut of html code]